# How do I send e-mail using Gmail's SMTP and Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, ssl, gmail, indy

I'm using Delphi 2009 and the lastest Indy 10 from svn to send e-mails using SMTP, but it doesn't work with Gmail (Google Apps hosted domain). When I try to send an e-mail I get "Must issue a STARTTLS command first".

I tried Googling about it and I found several forums and several solutions, but they all just bashed some code or just said I needed an OpenSLL DLL, which so far isn't very clear to me exactly what I need.

Can someone please tell exactly which DLL I need and what do I have to change in the my TIdSMTP and TIdMessage objects in order to send the e-mails through Gmail's SMTP server?

Also, an explanation about why this authentication is different and what the DLL is for is very welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps [Marco can help you](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/tip_indy_gmail.html)...

Edit: with this link [to the source code](http://www.marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail.html).

Comment: That worked, thanks, one thing that I'm still not sure, do I really need the OpenSSL dlls? The article says nothing about it, but when I tested it gives me an exception "Cannot load library" if I try to send e-mails without the dlls. This is still not very clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: You need the OpenSSL DLLs if you use Indy's native SSL IOHandler class,  There are third-party IOHandler classes available that do not use the DLLs.

Comment: Can you please mention one of these third-party classes @RemyLebeau ?

Comment: @delphirules: [Eldos SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/) includes an [Indy IOHandler class](https://www.eldos.com/documentation/sbb/documentation/usingindy.html) that uses SBB's own SSL/TLS implementation instead of OpenSSL.  Also, in a future release, Indy will likely provide a native IOHandler class for Microsoft's CryptoAPI/SChannel SSL/TLS implementation as an alternative to OpenSSL on Windows.